# OGL 4+/ GLSL / C++ - Trailing planetary orbits

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vbo

I am working on a solar system simulator and am trying right now to figure out how to do trailing orbits in C++ / OpenGL / GLSL that look similar to this:

[Reference](http://i1.wp.com/74.207.228.183/main/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/cent_sag.png)

The problem is that **I do not have static orbits**, the position of a planet is updated every frame.

All planets are instanced from one class. I have an idea how to do this but not sure its technically possible.

Please advise (wether it is to improve my idea or something better).

**Concept**:

1. **Have one VBO with specific set of vertex data, say 8 vertecies as example**
2. **Create IBO that describes linkage between each consecutive point**

The idea is to have a "treadmill" of verticies, where the first one moves with the planet:

```
IBO : [ 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 ]
```

---------------^ make glsl update only first element in vbo, which means in vbo:

```
VBO : [ v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 | v5 | v6 | v7 | v8 ]
```

---------------^ Current vertex to update for each rendercall

3. **Then as planet & v1 moves a set distance D from v2**

Set last vertex position to next orbit-position, ie move it forward in chain:

```
IBO : [ 8 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 ]
```

---------------^ current index to update, which means in vbo:

```
VBO : [ v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 | v5 | v6 | v7 | v8 ]
```

-------------------------------------------------------------------------^ Current vertex to update for each rendercall

Does this make any sence? I really like the idea of reusing vertecies, give them a lifetime (for fading color) and then.. do that relink? Is it even possible to manipulate the index buffer at GPU level?

Perhaps my mind just wandered into a alley of stupid, maybe someone here has a better idea?

Comment: You're over-optimizing.  Passing a dozen or so vertices to compose a 'trailing orbit line' is a trivial amount of data in the grand scheme of things, so passing an entire buffer from CPU to GPU every frame won't slow down your rendering (assuming you're rendering, 10s or 100s of planets, and not millions).  Yes, you could probably implement a circular buffer in this fashion, but the added complexity wouldn't be worth any performance gain.

Comment: I agree, I moved on to preallocating a circle and am now trying to figure out how to update each position... which proves to be rather difficult...

Answer (score 0):

i dont really understand what you are trying to do with this code, but as far as i understand when you change the IBO you actually change the order of the triangles that make up the geometry, and if you have a probleme with animating the position of the planets then the solutions is pretty forward,

```
for each planet
{
glUniformMatrix4fv(matLocation, 1, GL_FALSE/*Or GL_TRUE depends on you implementation*/, planet.getModelMatrix());
planet.Render();
}
```

and the vertex shader would look like:

```
...
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projMatrix;
...

void main() {
...
gl_Position = projMatrix*viewMatrix*modelMatrix*in_vertexPosition;
...
}
```

and if this is not what you are seeking for then can please specifie a little bit more!

Comment: No, the position of each planet is already computed, this has nothing to do with the mesh geometry. Rather, I want to draw a trailing orbit line - ie line of motion of each planetary object, a circle would be the simplest case. But imagine a circle where each segment fades the further the planet moves away from it (see reference image in my post). The idea is to somehow reuse old verticies, to move the last up the chain.

Comment: aah Ok o got you, you want to create the lines lefted behind planets movement right?
what i would do, is to create new VBO that holds the line data, (start and end in case of simple line alot of vertices in case of Bezier lines) and just render them.

Comment: Do you mean to create a new VBO each frame? We have narrowed down at the point where Im lost: How do I update the VBO? Right now I see the problem as having the planet going over a railway where the track in front of it is 'not updatet' and whats behind it is. So my idea was what you see above, to move the last vertex up the chain and somehow relink - is that overcomplicating things? ... It propably means changing the indexbuffer, saying "this is how the points are linked now" every update..

Comment: Following up on my previous comment: The other way is to instead just have an ellipse of points, that eliminates the optimization of only having visible ones in memory, but still - how to update specific indexes in a VBO then? Do I tag somehow each vertex.. Im not an expert on VBO's, my brain tends to think in CPU code still.

Comment: Ok, if this is the idea you want to expande and you are woring about performance and you want eliminite invisible objects then you want to go with batching as it's the most simple yet effecient way of drawing little sprites, so you will update your array of points in the CPU then just send them to the GPU with glSubBufferData(...) or more effective ways, and then maybe use a Geometry shader to read points and output lines to be rendered. now if you are intrested you can contact me to give code example for batching (sorry don't have a github acount).

Comment: Following up on my previous comment: updating the index buffer may not be good because you will need to update the points position when the planet move you will need to hide some, and render some and following your suggestion u will not be able to do it easlly, so if you are intersed in my idea i can help u, just email.(the email is in the profile informations)

Comment: I really cant find your email =) Ive been clicking everywhere on your profile (quite novice stack-user). Are you sure its not just visible to you?

Comment: and yes I do very much want to see that example you had =)

Comment: Ok here is it: arezki.elmehdi@gmail.com